# AngularJS ngOptions sort array

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have been trying to use `ng-options` to display an array of fonts in a select sorted alphabetically by the value of the items in the array.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-options="font for font in webfonts | orderBy:'font'" name="fonts">
     <option value="">Choose a font</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.webfonts = [ 
        'Abel', 'Crafty Girls' , 'Lato' , 'Average',
        'Corben', 'Quicksand', ... ];
```

I've tried changing the value in `orderBy` and other things. I've read through the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) and all comments.

What am I missing? Is this supposed to only work on objects?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="font for font in webfonts | orderBy:'toString()' " name="fonts">
```

1. You need to add ng-model to correctly make the binding works for a list of strings.
2. You can use `toString()` to sort if the input contains a list of strings. Since the expression of `orderBy` can be a Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the <, =, > operator.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rL9R4/)**</kbd>

Comment: @ChrisB Because `toString()` is available in any `string` object in the prototype. This is indeed a trick, and it deserves to keep in mind forever.

Comment: It works because `.toString()` is a property of the string in the array `webfonts`, and `orderBy` is expecting a property of the object given (`font`). At the same time `toString()` returns the value of `font` which happens to be exactly what I want to order by. Is this right? Am I understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation specifies, the string argument is for object properties, not for primitives. I think, as elementary as it sounds, you have to create a function on the scope that simply returns the argument, and pass that to `orderBy`.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfv42/)!

Comment: As the documentation specifies, you can pass a function name and the result of it is used as the comparison value!